# query string params

Tags: url, segments, parameters, path, google-analytics

Got a site that want to use tracking in URLS like http://domain.com/segment_1/segment_2/?utm_campaign=google

Now this works fine locally but on the production server, it renders the 404.

On MAMP I've set the config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO' and have tried this in production but still get the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide your htaccess file please?

Comment: sure https://gist.github.com/stevieg83/6793037

Comment: Did you try 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1' on the production server? Also try:  http://domain.com/segment_1/segment_2/&utm_campaign=google

Comment: nice one Peter, add it as an answer :-) htaccess is Internet voodoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1
```

Instead of...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

Normally the first thing I try when query strings go wrong!

Comment: seems I jumped the gun a little bit here. Although it fixed the query string problem, it introduced a bug where a single entry view wasn't displaying the right content. For example http://www.pilot.no/aktiviteter/detaljer/opptaksprver-stavanger-03.10 would wrongly show location as Stockholm

Comment: Why/how would the htaccess rewrites impact on the geographical location? It shows Stavanger for me...?

Comment: yeah, had to revert it back for the client so in production it's fine. Here's the staging link http://d.pr/f8ob - click on Stavanger and you'll see

Comment: Sorry, thought I'd commented on this already. Hamar works fine, so I'm not sure this is an htaccess issue - why would it work fine for one and not the others. You'll need to explain how your getting the location, currently in the source I see "stockholm" being sent to Google Maps, so there has to be an issue in your template code, as the displayed data shows the correct location...?